Trying to add an html sidebar that will add images picked from a list
So I want a sode bar pop-up thats just a list of buttons with different names, and you click on a button and it inserts the named image. I have a script that sucessfully adds an image, and I have a working sidebar for adding contacts, and I tried mashing them together, and was not successful. Im pretty new to the scripting, and I know nothing about HTML, so its kind of impressive I have getten as far as I have with my main document (if I say so myself).
Any help making this work would be awesome. I want to just have one setup, then Ill copy as needed to make others. Like to a purged out sheet below.
Thanks in advance!
Sheet Link
The side bar pops up as it should, but nothing happens when I click the button.
script:
function imagemenu()
{ 
  var form = 
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Images').setTitle('Add Images');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Tools')
      .addItem('Add Image', 'imagemenu')

      .addToUi();     
  
}

function imageAdder(){
  const img_url = (img_url1);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(img_url);
  const rd = response.getContent();
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(rd, 'image/png','MyImageName');
  sh.insertImage(blob, 15, 58);
};

html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
      .narrow {
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      // JavaScript code for SubmitRecord and other functions


      function image01() {
        document.getElementById("displayReturn").innerHTML = "";

        var img_url1 = ('https://thevasilcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/VJ-CC.png');
        
        // Call the Google Apps Script function with the form data
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnBack)
          .imageAdder(img_url1);
      }


      function returnBack(stringBack) {
        document.getElementById("displayReturn").innerHTML = stringBack;
        document.getElementById("img_url1").value = '';

      }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div style="padding: 10px">

        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow">
            <input type="button" value="Cross Country" onclick="image01()" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="displayReturn"></div>
    <script>getints();</script>
    <script>getpaytype();</script>
  </body>
</html>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

class contact {
    constructor(name, number, email) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Number = number;
        this.Email = email;
    }    
}

const contacts = [new contact("Ben", "9883092", "Ben@frot.com"), new contact("Muder", "20993902", "Harddive@light.org") ] ; // Number of buttons to create
const buttonList = document.getElementById('buttonList');

for (let i = 1; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
    const listItem = document.createElement(contacts[i].Name);
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = `Button ${i}`;
    button.onclick = () => alert(`Button ${i} clicked!`);

    listItem.appendChild(button);
    buttonList.appendChild(listItem);
}

you need to set the context

Hi Marlon, could you please add more description to your answer? many thanks.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I apriciate your atempt to help me out, but that needs to be dumbed down alot. I am not a coder, and I dont understand "set the context", or even understand how to apply the code you pasted in there. Im kind of a hack lol
